# ClickOnce deployment: Cleaning up older versions in the server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

How can I deploy a ClickOnce application from "Publish" in Visual Studio 2008 and only keep the latest publish in the "Application Files" ?

I tend to do many "Publish"'ings.. and after a while my distribution server is full of old versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't need to keep the old versions available if you don't mind not allowing people to upgrade incrementally.

ie. Delete the old versions Application Files manually. There isn't an automatic option.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do it manually, as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the older versions that remain the in \Application Files\ directory, I think you have to clean those up manually.